# Using LEFT or INNER JOIN and WHERE in SQL ACCESS

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, where-clause

I have this query in MS Access:

```
SELECT 
    tbl_produtos.NomeProduto,
    tbl_produtos.PrecoVenda,
    tbl_precos_especiais.PrecoVenda
FROM
    tbl_produtos
        LEFT JOIN
    tbl_precos_especiais ON tbl_precos_especiais.ID_Produto = tbl_produtos.ID_Produto;
```

Results are like this
[image: Results are like this]

But on tbl_precos_especiais, I have a field called ID_CliFor, and I want to put a WHERE on the QUERY to filter the results on this field:

```
SELECT 
    tbl_produtos.NomeProduto,
    tbl_produtos.PrecoVenda,
    tbl_precos_especiais.PrecoVenda
FROM
    tbl_produtos
        LEFT JOIN
    tbl_precos_especiais ON tbl_precos_especiais.ID_Produto = tbl_produtos.ID_Produto
WHERE
    tbl_precos_especiais.ID_CliFor = 268;
```

Results are like this
[image: Results are like this]

I wanted to bring all the results from the tbl_produtos anyway, the ones that are empty on the tbl_precos_especiais, so I will have a listbox where the user can change and input new values. But I dont have any idea how to do it.

Comment: The WHERE condition effectively turns the LEFT JOIN into an INNER JOIN.

Answer (score 1):

Move the condition the `on` clause:

```
SELECT p.NomeProduto, p.PrecoVenda, pe.PrecoVenda
FROM tbl_produtos p LEFT JOIN
     tbl_precos_especiais pe
     ON pe.ID_Produto = p.ID_Produto AND pe.ID_CliFor = 268;
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering. I got an "join expression not supported" error, and it highlights this part: "pe.ID_CliFor = 268"

Comment: @FabioGomes . . . This construct is standard SQL and certainly supported by MySQL.  Have you mistagged the question and you are really using some obtuse database?